# Postgres Join query hanging forever

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've these two tables (cant share due to security) both tables has almost 250,000 records in each table, using Postgres version 9.6 and below is the execution query plan. This query is hanging forever.

Any quick help?

```
CREATE TABLE test.TableA (
    last_update_date date NULL,
    src_party_country_id varchar(255) NULL,
    src_party_id varchar(255) NULL,
    country_cd varchar(255) NULL,
    lifecycle_status_cd varchar(10) NULL DEFAULT 'A'::character varying,
    violated varchar(1) NULL
);



CREATE TABLE test.TableB (
    last_update_date timestamp NULL,
    src_party_id varchar(255) NULL,
    "name" varchar(300) NULL,
    .....
);


TableA
ACCT    PROCID  1499    A   1970-01-01 00:00:00 MIGHTY      PDF 19582   3951931 A   DMIGHTY Y
ACCT    PROCID  1525    A   2019-05-17 00:00:00 MIGHTY  79175   PDF 19583   10005322    A   DMIGHTY Y
-- There could be multiple duplicate records or no records maching 

TableB
ACCT    PROCID  1525    A   17-05-19 12:00:00   MIGHTY  79175   PDF 630 10005322    A   DMIGHTY N
ACCT    PROCID  1499    A   01-01-70 12:00:00   MIGHTY      PDF 629 3951931 A   DMIGHTY N
```

Here is the explain -

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..1258454.96 rows=489356232944 width=1409)
  ->  Seq Scan on TableA child  (cost=0.00..7323.64 rows=233382 width=60)
        Filter: (((src_system)::text = 'ABC'::text) AND ((isBuly)::text = 'N'::text) AND ((status)::text = ANY ('{A,P,T,X}'::text[])))
  ->  Index Scan using TableA_id_idx on c_l_party parent  (cost=0.42..3.59 rows=177 width=1349)
        Index Cond: ((src_party_id)::text = (child.src_party_id)::text)
```

Even this query is hanging for prolong

```
SELECT  count(*) FROM  
       test.TableA_COUNTRY CHILD  
       test.TableB PARENT,  
WHERE  
       PARENT.violated = CHILD.violated;
       AND CHILD.SRC_SYSTEM = 'ABC'  
       AND CHILD.isBuly = 'N' ;
```

Comment: Is the join on `violated` correct? Because this looks like a boolean field. With 250000 records per table, this could return somewhere around (250000/2)^2 results

Comment: Also, are the estimates correct?

Comment: You didn't provide the `CREATE` statements of the indexes. Have you made sure it doesn't "hang" because another transaction holds a lock on one of the objects involved?

Comment: Almost 500 billion records, does that make sense to you?